# How do I get Django multi-argument url tags working?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I can't figure out which part I'm mucking up!

The error I'm getting is:

> Reverse for 'update_rating' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{u'pk': 9, u'on_title': True}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['y/update_rating/(?P[\w-]+)/(?P[True|False])$']

**url.py:** (the first one is the one in contention)

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Must be last url pattern, otherwise everything /y/ will use this pattern
    url('^update_rating/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/(?P<on_title>[True|False])$', views.update_rating, name='update_rating'),
    url('^add_thing_with_rating/(?P<parent_pk>[\w-]+)$', views.add_thing_with_rating, name='add_thing_with_rating'),
    url('^add_thing_with_rating/', views.add_thing_with_rating, name='add_thing_with_rating'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-\/]+)/?', views.thing_page),
]
```

The html tag from **thing_page.html**:

```
{% url 'update_rating' pk=thing.pk on_title=True %}
```

The view function from **views.py**:

```
def update_rating(request, pk=None, on_title=False):
```

I'm quite confused by this whole way of handling URLs, so in addition to solving my problem, if you have any further advice on handling URLs don't hesitate to add that to your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with this pattern:

```
url('^update_rating/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/(?P<on_title>[True|False])$', views.update_rating, name='update_rating')
```

You passed wrong regexp to variables, `pk` must match integers so `\d+` and booleans must match words `\w+`

```
url('^update_rating/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<on_title>\w+)/$', views.update_rating, name='update_rating')
```